# HttpRequestMessage POST

Tags: c#, post, httprequest

I'm attempting to send a [json](https://www.json.org/) "styled" string via [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx).
I have created to following method below in hope of sending the response message successfully.

```
class Foo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Vendors
    /// </summary>
    public enum Vendor
    {
        [Description("https://someSite.com")]
        FOO = 0x001
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send a POST response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vendor"></param>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    public static async void SendResponseAsync(Vendor vendor, string data)
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, vendor.EnumDescriptionToString()))
            {
                var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
                httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
                Console.WriteLine(result.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        });
        await task;
    }
}
```

And I'm calling it with the following;

```
static void Main()
{
    string jsonText = "{\"apikey\": \"someAPIkey\",\"type\": \"ItemRegistered\",   \"order\": \"999999\",   \"item\": \"99999\",    \"datetime\": \"2018-10-12 01:27:11 GMT\"}";
    Foo.SendResponseAsync(Foo.Vendor.FOO, jsonText);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The error I'm receiving is [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) now you could say that that is my issue right there, and indeed you are correct, however,
 I'm wondering why is it that when I use [PostMan](https://web.postman.co/) that I receive an error that says the order number is not recognized? in json format,
So I understand that the order number is not correct, however, why is it not showing in my console app? Is my method for POSTING correct?

Answer (score 9):

You should pass serialized json representation into StringContent. You `json` variable is of type object instead, and when you call `ToString()` it gives you something like class type. If your `data` is already serialized json, just pass that.

Or, if you have an object, pass it like this:

```
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```